# Importando dados de um TXT para uma StringGrid

Tags: delphi

Tenho um *stringgrid*, e preciso importar um arquivo *txt* para ele, porém preciso pegar todas as linhas de acordo com as posições, e não tenho ideia de como fazer, fiz pesquisas, mas sem sucesso.

Preciso desse tipo de código para me informar de como fazer comparação de duas `stringgrids` com uma DLL de uma impressora fiscal, e tenho que copiar essas colunas respectivamente de acordo com a posição de cada uma.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Portugues.Para evitar que sua resposta seja sinalizada e consequentemente fechada, sugiro que você adicione o que pesquisou, se encontrou algo, o que encontrou ou o que sabe de Delphi que possa te ajudar nessa tarefa. Aqui a comunidade costuma premiar o esforço em fazer uma boa pergunta com ótimas respostas, portanto boa sorte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sou muito a favor de dar o peixe pra galera, então vou **tentar** te ensinar a pescar:

Temos o seguinte arquivo de texto, chamado teste.txt(*que deve estar na mesma pasta do executável, para facilitar nosso teste*):

```
123456789012345678901234567890
COL1      COL2      COL3      
DADO1     DADO2     DADO3     
TESTE1    TESTE2    TESTE3
```

Note que a linha `123456789012345678901234567890` não deve ir para o arquivo de texto, considere ela uma régua, assumindo que o TXT que você está trabalhando seja tipado.

Considerando que seu txt seja pequeno, usaremos uma `StringList` para captar os dados dele da seguinte forma:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  arquivo : TStringList;
  i : integer;
begin
  arquivo := TStringList.Create;
  arquivo.LoadFromFile('teste.txt');
end;
```

Agora seu arquivo está todo na `StringList` Arquivo e está pronta para ser comparada com qualquer valor da seguinte forma:

```pascal
  for i := 0 to arquivo.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Showmessage('Primeiro campo: ' + copy(arquivo[i],1,10));   //Primeiro Campo
    Showmessage('Segundo campo: ' + copy(arquivo[i],11,10));  //Segundo Campo
    Showmessage('Terceiro campo: ' + copy(arquivo[i],21,10));  //Terceiro Campo
  end;
```

A partir daí fica com você a inserção no `StringGrid`, a validação e utilização da DLL da Bematech, Daruma ou qualquer que seja o fabricante. O laço criado vai percorrer toda a `StringList`. Lembrando que ele se inicia no 0 e vai até `arquivo.count - 1` pelo índice do `TStringList` se iniciar no 0 e não no 1.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, a questão é que estou reiniciando o meu treinamento em delphi, e não estou muito familiarizado com a língua, porém irei resolver com base na sua resposta, que por sinal foi ótima, agora tenho ideia por onde começar, assim que possível irei postar meus códigos. Obrigado Filipe! ;]

Comment: @perdeu Obrigado! Passarei a usar essa notação para código a partir de agora.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, quando highlight da tag não pegar vc colocar manualmente, [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150/91) tem uma lista, caso precise.